# Onbeforeunload doesn't work on Safari and Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, safari, onbeforeunload

I'm using onbeforeunload to call a function when the user leaves the page. It works fine with IE and Firefox, but not with Safari and Google Chrome.
Is there any solution or alternative option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using this event to call a web method, and this is not supported in Safari. This is because safari doesn't support an asynchronous request to the server. So to address that I found a way to call the web method using jQuery and set the (async) property to false. 
This link might help http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/